# Can i store mysql result in apc cache ?

Tags: php, mysql, caching, apc

Consider this sample code :

```
    $storyID = 1;
    $detailsCache = 'details'.$storyID;
    if(!apc_exists($detailsCache)){
    $phases_details = <<<SQL
            SELECT stp.stp_id, 
               stp.stp_name, 
               stp.stp_position, 
               FROM story_phase stp
               WHERE stp.stp_stl_id = $storyID
    SQL;
   $resultdetails = Helpers::execute_query($phases_details,"Get phase details failed.");
**// i cant cache the result here like apc_store($detailsCache, $phases_details);**
}
$result_phases_details = apc_fetch($detailsCache);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_phases_details)){
// some logic
}
```

Any better way to cache the result ?

Comment: Where does `Helpers::execute_query` come from?

Comment: Sorry ignore that. Its a generic class with execute_query($query) function which does mysql_query($query);

Comment: Yeah, I was worried about that. You shouldn't be using `mysql_query` in new applications, and secondly, it looks like `$storyID` is not escaped properly. Both these things are pretty bad.

Comment: Agree.! Thanks a lot for the suggestion. :) Any idea on how to implement caching in a better way?.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the MySQL result is a resource (which it seems to be based on your later use of mysql_fetch_assoc), that cannot be stored via APC. However, if you read out the result into PHP data structures first, you can store those in APC for later retrieval.

```
$resultdetails = Helpers::execute_query($phases_details,"Get phase details failed.");
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultdetails)) {
  $results[] = $row;
}
apc_store($detailsCache, $results);

// Retrieval:
$results = apc_fetch($detailsCache);
foreach ($results as $row) {
  // some logic...
}
```

Comment: Rite ! IF u see for the first time when we run the query we use while loop to store values in cache and a foreach to retrive it.! Any way to optimize it ?